# Not able to see other partitions in ubuntu file manager with GParted running

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have an ubuntu dual booted alongside windows 10. Initially I was able to see other partitions such as C drive and D drive that I could see in windows file explorer. But after I moved some partitions to combine two unallocated spaces/partitions to create a home directory, I found out that I am not able to see these partitions as well as other partitions that I could see initially. I had been searching for a solution but couldn't find one. Pl. help ASAP as it is very urgent. I have attached some screenshots for reference.
Thanks in advance.

Gparted screenshot- I wanted the selected partition to become the home partition.
[image: Gparted screenshot- I wanted the selected partition to become the home partition.]

Ubuntu file manager screenshot
[image: Ubuntu file manager screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When GParted runs, all the partitions get hidden in the file manager (happens in most file managers, an exception being Thunar).

I can see that GParted is running in the second screenshot, and maybe that's why you cannot see them anymore in your file manager (you said that you could see them initially).

You would most likely be able to access them after closing GParted.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked!